# Can you include an external docker image in an AWS Lambda function?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-ecr

I have an docker image that I want to import into my AWS Lambda function, and in researching how to do so (if possible), I seem to seeing multiple references to using Amazon ECR as well. I'm looking to find out definitively if I need to use ECR, or not?

Comment: Afaik, Lambda supports container image deployments from the Amazon Elastic Container Registry (ECR) only.

Comment: As mentioned Lambda requires container images be in ECR, additionally, there are [several requirements](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/images-create.html) for container images to work with Lambda, such as implementing the  runtime interface client.  Generally purpose Docker images are unlikely to work as is.